# Create alias from stdout

Tags: bash, stdout, alias

I am trying to dynamically create alias' from the output of another command line tool.

For example:

```
> MyScript
blender="/opt/apps/blender/blender/2.79/blender"
someOtherAlias="ls -l"
```

I am trying the following code:

```
MyScript | {
   while IFS= read -r line;
   do
      `echo alias $line`;
   done;
}
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
bash: alias: -l": not found
```

Just trying to run this command by itself gives me the same error:

```
> `echo 'alias someOtherAlias="ls -l"'`
bash: alias: -l": not found
```

But obviously the following command does work:

```
alias someOtherAlias="ls -l"
```

I've tried to find someone else who may have done this before, but none of my searches have come up with anything.

I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Comment: what don't you use `source` on `MyScript` instead?

Comment: MyScript is actually shorthand for a python script that reads and processes a bunch of .ini files and then outputs the results to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how bash (and posix shells) command parsing and quoting works and see difference between syntax and literal argument: for example `'.."..'` `"..'.."` are litteral quotes in an argument whereas `"` or `'` are shell syntax and are not part of argument

also, enabling tacing with `set -x` may help to understand :

```
set -x
`echo 'alias someOtherAlias="ls -l"'`
++ echo 'alias someOtherAlias="ls -l"'
+ alias 'someOtherAlias="ls' '-l"'
bash: alias: -l": not found
```

bash sees 3 words : `alias`, `someOtherAlias="ls` and `-l"`.
and alias loops over its arguments if they contain a `=` it create an alias otherwise it displays what alias argument is as `-l"` is not an alias it shows the error.

Note also as backquotes means command is run in a subshell (can be seen with mutiple `+` in trace) it will have no effect in current shell.

`eval` may be use to reinterpret literal as bash syntax (or to parse again a string).

So following should work, but be careful using eval on arbitrary arguments (from user input) can run arbitrary command.

```
eval 'alias someOtherAlias="ls -l"'
```

Finally also as bash commands after pipe are also run in subshell.

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    `echo alias $line`;
done <MyScript
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was super helpful.  I will go back to using eval.  I had avoided it because it seemed both clumsy and a bit of a security issue.  But I already have code in both this shell script I am trying to write as well as "MyScript" that check the entire chain to make sure they are owned by root and only writable by root.

Comment: Upon further reading of your answer, it would seem that even if I use eval, I won't get what I want because of the fact that bash commands after pipe are run in a subshell. It would seem that my best bet would be to fully assemble a complete, multiline (with individual commands separated by ';') bash command in "MyScript" and pass that back via stdOut to be eval'd in my script.  As long as "MyScript" and all of its inputs are owned by root and only writable by root, that should be relatively ok I think.